# Multi-line org mode formula definitions

Tags: org-mode, org-table

Org tables are great! But sometimes, for non-trivial cases, the formulas get a little unwieldy. E.g.:

```
#+TBLFM: @III+1$3..@IIII-1$>='(let ((l (-non-nil (mapcar* (lambda (w v) (when (equal w $2) (string-to-number v))) (list @II+1$2..@III-1$2) (list @II+1..@III-1))))) (/ (-sum l) (float (length l))));E%.1f
```

<sup>(There might be a denser Calc syntax for the above, but that's beside the point.)</sup>

Editing it as it is all cramped in one line is not great. There is also no way to document the formula or its parts.

Is there a way to split the formula into multiple lines?

If not, is there a way to define an Emacs Lisp function within the same file, so that it is evaluated automatically when the `.org` file is opened?

Comment: Or a way to fold it and toggle visibility like a drawer, maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Org-Babel allows creating functions (written in, but not limited to, emacs-lisp), which can then be referenced in table formulas:

```
#+NAME: add
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
  (+ a b)
  ; feel free to use as many lines or comments here!
  ; press C-c ' here to edit in emacs-lisp-mode
#+END_SRC

|----+----+-----|
|  a |  b | a+b |
|----+----+-----|
|  1 |  2 |   3 |
| 10 | 10 |  20 |
|  5 | -7 |  -2 |
|----+----+-----|
#+TBLFM: $3='(org-sbe "add" (a $1) (b $2))
```

However, passing ranges to such functions is problematic (because of some serious shortcomings of the `org-sbe` function's implementation).

Answer (score -1):

You'll find it in the org manual [Multi-line org mode formula definitions](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/39289/multi-line-org-mode-formula-definitions) .

```
| x | y |
|---+---|
| 1 |   |
| 2 |   |
#+TBLFM: $2=$1*1
#+TBLFM: $2=$1*2
```

Comment: No idea what this has to do with my question. Your link is also broken, it links to this page.